# Gulp acting differently on remote server

Tags: node.js, gulp

I run the same gulpfile on local and remote. On local, everything is fine but when on remote, both "vendors" and "assets" tasks are not doing anything and there's no error when I run the gulp. Below is my gulp script -

```
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
    gutil   = require('gulp-util'),
    clean   = require('gulp-clean'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    concat  = require('gulp-concat'),
    rename  = require('gulp-rename'),
    jshint  = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify  = require('gulp-uglify'),
    less    = require('gulp-less'),
    csso    = require('gulp-csso'),
    jade    = require('gulp-jade'),
    es      = require('event-stream'),
    embedlr = require('gulp-embedlr'),
    refresh = require('gulp-livereload'),
    express = require('express'),
    http    = require('http'),
    lr      = require('tiny-lr')();

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    // Clear the destination folder
    gulp.src('dist/**/*.*', { read: false })
        .pipe(clean({ force: true }));
});

// Vendor Files

    // var vendors = {
    //     js: [ './bower_components/**/ZeroClipBoard.js'],
    //     assets: ['./bower_components/**/ZeroClipBoard.swf']
    // };

// Compile JS

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return es.concat(
        // Detect errors and potential problems in your JavaScript code
        // You can enable or disable default JSHint options in the .jshintrc file


        // Concatenate, minify and copy all JavaScript (except vendor scripts)
        gulp.src(['./src/js/**/*.js'])
            .pipe(concat('main.js'))
            .pipe(uglify({mangle: false}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
            .pipe(refresh(lr))



)});

// Copy Vendor Script and Assets

gulp.task('assets', function () {
        return gulp.src(['./bower_components/**/ZeroClipBoard.swf'], {base: './'})   
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/vendors'));
});

gulp.task('vendors', function () {
        return gulp.src(['./bower_components/**/ZeroClipBoard.js'])
            .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
            .pipe(uglify({mangle: false}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});

// Compile LESS files
gulp.task('styles', function () {
return gulp.src('./src/less/styles.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(rename('styles.css'))
    .pipe(csso())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
    .pipe(refresh(lr));
});

gulp.task('templates', function () {
// Compile Jade files
return gulp.src('./src/jade/index.jade')
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(rename('index.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
    .pipe(refresh(lr));
});

gulp.task('server', function () {
    // Create a HTTP server for static files
    var port = 3000;
    var app = express();
    var server = http.createServer(app);

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

    server.on('listening', function () {
        gutil.log('Listening on http://localhost:' + server.address().port);
    });

    server.on('error', function (err) {
        if (err.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {
            gutil.log('Address in use, retrying...');
            setTimeout(function () {
                server.listen(port);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

    server.listen(port);
});

gulp.task('lr-server', function () {
    // Create a LiveReload server
    lr.listen(35729, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            gutil.log(err);
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {

    // Watch .less files and run tasks if they change
    gulp.watch('./src/less/**/*.less', ['styles']);

    // Watch .jade files and run tasks if they change
    gulp.watch('./src/jade/index.jade', ['templates']);

    // Watch .js files
    gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);

});

// The dist task (used to store all files that will go to the server)
gulp.task('dist', ['clean', 'styles', 'templates', 'scripts', 'vendors']);

// The default task (called when you run `gulp`)
gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'styles', 'templates', 'scripts', 'assets', 'vendors', 'lr-server', 'server', 'watch']);
```

Comment: My guess is that the destination folders do not already exist or have incorrect permissions, or both.

Comment: But the thing is if the folders do not existed, gulp.dest would have created the folder. I have re-checked the permissions. My "scripts" and "vendors" tasks output into same folder. I could see the outputted .js file from "scripts" but not from "vendors".